# Copy some figure properties

Tags: matlab

I have plots saved as .fig. What commands should I use to apply all properties of one plot to another. Most importantly I need to copy linewidth of the line, axes, all fonts, background color, size and positions.

Comment: [`get`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) would probably be a good start...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: How to change the linewidth in a figure before actually plotting some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257357/matlab-how-to-change-the-linewidth-in-a-figure-before-actually-plotting-some)

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Load the *.fig into your Matlab workspace and then generate code for the image. The option is available at "**File->Generate code...**" on the figure window. Save the script in *.m format and after that just change the data and run the script. You could also modify the code as per your requirements.